# Problem in Fourier Series curve fit of data in Python

Tags: python, fft, curve-fitting

[Velocity Profile](http://file:///J:/Shayor/New%20Volume/ME%202K16/Thesis/Presentation%20and%20Word%20file/Velocity%20Profile.htm)

I developed a code to fit the curve.But my "y" doesn't match the extracted "Y".Can you please tell me why.I can't find the error.Could you point it out anyone?TIA.I have tried to fit the curve using 20 fourier series steps.

[Data Used X-1st Col and Y-2nd Col](http://file:///J:/Shayor/New%20Volume/ME%202K16/Thesis/Presentation%20and%20Word%20file/Velocity%20Profile.htm)
Details were added.But this line is for correction of the code.The code is actually simple.You can ignore prints of values.

```
        import xlrd
        import math
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        loc = ("/content/sample_data/Plot.xlsx")
     
        work_bk = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
        sheet = work_bk.sheet_by_index(0)
        sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
    
        ##For extracting values of time
        #X dim-(118,1)
         X=np.array([])
         for i in range(sheet.nrows):
          X=np.append(X,sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
         #print(type(X))
         X= X.reshape(118,1)
         #print(X.shape)
      
         ##For extracting values of velocity
         #Y dim-(118,1)
         Y=np.array([])
         for j in range(sheet.nrows):
           Y=np.append(Y,sheet.cell_value(j, 1))
         Y= Y.reshape(118,1)
         print(Y)
    
         #For defining An & Bn matrices
         c=np.array([])
         d=np.array([]) 
         A=np.array([])
         B=np.array([]) 
         E=np.array([]) 
         F=np.array([])

 

    for m in range(118):
     for n in range(21):
       C=math.cos(2*math.pi*n*X[m])
       c=np.append(c,C) # c dim-(1,21)

   
  
     D=math.sin(2*math.pi*n*X[m]) 
     d=np.append(d,D) # d dim-(1,21))
   
 
   A=np.append(A,c)
   B=np.append(B,d)
   c=np.array([])
   d=np.array([])

   #A dim-(118,20)
   #B dim-(118,20)

   A = A.reshape(118,21)
   B = B.reshape(118,21)
  
   Z=np.hstack((A,B))    

   #Cn=np.linalg.solve(Z,Y) #Doesnt work.
   Cn=np.linalg.pinv(Z).dot(Y)  
   #print(Cn)
   #Cn=Cn.reshape(21,2)
   #print(Cn)


   y=np.array([])
   V=0
   for m in range(118):
    #for n in range(21):
    # if (2*n)<41 and (2*n+1)<42:
    V=V+(An*math.cos(2*math.pi*n*X[m]))+(Bn*math.sin(2*math.pi*n*X[m]))
    y=np.append(y,V)
    
   y=y.reshape(118,1)
   print(y)
   plt.plot(X,y)
   plt.show()
   #description of Cn=[[An],[Bn]]


   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jtqf.png
```

Comment: Graph look pretty good. Can you elaborate your problem in more detail?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: ok sure @boetis .Actually this is my first time posting this.But I thought a complete code may help to run the code and understand the logic.

Comment: @mikuszefski ofcourse.I tried to fit a curve of a blood flow data.If you see the image "Velocity Profile" I have attached with the post you can understand what I am trying to achieve.So what I did was-
1)Extracted data from a CSV file. 
2) Calculated the coefficients of An and Bn (that is for each X value 21 pairs of coefficients which are cos(2*pi*n*X) and sin (2*pi*n*X) )
3)Stacked them side by side to create the final 118 X 42 matrix "Cn"
4)Used the "np.linalg.pinv().dot() function to calculate the "y" which is supposed to match "Y" extracted from the file.
Please help me out.

Comment: Hi, This part of the explanation I already got. And sure you want to match the data with the fitted graph. And again, the  result looked (don't get the image right now) good to me. What do you mean by "don't match"?

Comment: @mikuszefski hello.Thank you so much for giving time to read that overtly long explanation of my question.Sorry for misunderstanding you. I want a smooth curve like the one as in "Velocity Profile" image with no oscillations whatsoever.Also having that means getting the "y" I found using the code to match exactly the "Y" I extracted at the beginning of the code.
P.S:I have now attached the CSV file for debugging attempt if you want to run the code.

Comment: Sorry, but your links are messed up, can you check the please. So if I get it right, you are unhappy with the fact that the Fourier series is oscillating in a region where your data is flat. What about the sharp peaks? Is is "okay" that the series is more rounded?